# Update DataGridView bound to datatable with new incoming rows continuously

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, datagridview, datatable

I have a datatable which is first bound to a binding source, and then the binding source is bound to the datagrid's datasource:

```
bindingSource1.DataSource = table;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
```

This has been working fine for static data.

1) Now if new rows are being added to my table (the rate at which this happens is a different part of the implementation and not directly related to the current question), how do I automatically refresh the datagridview so that it shows **the rows as they are coming in, and shows a scrollbar if needed?** Note that I already have a scrollbar in the grid so I might not need anything new to actually show it.

2) Note also that the following might happen: The user might not have selected to automatically update for some time, and so when they do there's more rows to show in the grid (say for example there are 1000 new rows that need to be added to the grid since the last update). Can the same solution for 1) also apply for this case?

I am using .NET 3.5. Would it be possible to use a table adapter (I am not working with a database however)? Or just do a bindingsource1.resetbindings()?

Comment: Are you in control of the binding source? If you are then it is possible to notify bound components of a change in data from the binding source. You can then update your GridView when you're notified

Comment: @DanGardner The binding source is an object I can manipulate and use, yes. I assume what you are saying is the bindingsource1.ResetBindings() approach? But then how would this approach show 1000 new rows, or a couple new rows? And would it be able to show the new rows being added to the bottom as they come?

Comment: @Lason, yes sorry I somehow missed that last sentence! I've not worked with table adaptors personally, but I have successfully use the ResetBindings approach before

Comment: @Lason If you wanted help implementing a ResetBindings approach I can cobble together an example or guide you to some resources. The MSDN doc page is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f61k6akt(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: @DanGardner Thanks, I will write up a small example myself to see how it works.